# Understanding php static code analysis results

Tags: php, static-code-analysis, phpmd, phploc

I need an advice. Cant found any information about static code analysis results. For example, i use phploc, and generate report. But it's a good results or a bad i dont know.
As I understand what utility I wouldn't have enjoyed report must be the same. After seeing the results, you can solve the bad code or not.

Where i can see info about all lines in this results?

Thanks for help!

All what i found is:
Maximum Method Complexity must not be greater then 10.
CyclomaticComplexity
 - 1-4 is low
 - 5-7 indicates moderate complexity
 - 8-10 is high complexity
 - 11+ is very high complexity.

```
Directories                                          1
Files                                                3

Size
  Lines of Code (LOC)                              296
  Comment Lines of Code (CLOC)                     116 (39.19%)
  Non-Comment Lines of Code (NCLOC)                180 (60.81%)
  Logical Lines of Code (LLOC)                      50 (16.89%)
    Classes                                         43 (86.00%)
      Average Class Length                          14
        Minimum Class Length                         0
        Maximum Class Length                        43
      Average Method Length                          3
        Minimum Method Length                        1
        Maximum Method Length                        7
    Functions                                        0 (0.00%)
      Average Function Length                        0
    Not in classes or functions                      7 (14.00%)

Cyclomatic Complexity
  Average Complexity per LLOC                     0.22
  Average Complexity per Class                    4.67
    Minimum Class Complexity                      1.00
    Maximum Class Complexity                     12.00
  Average Complexity per Method                   2.00
    Minimum Method Complexity                     1.00
    Maximum Method Complexity                     4.00

Dependencies
  Global Accesses                                    0
    Global Constants                                 0 (0.00%)
    Global Variables                                 0 (0.00%)
    Super-Global Variables                           0 (0.00%)
  Attribute Accesses                                16
    Non-Static                                      16 (100.00%)
    Static                                           0 (0.00%)
  Method Calls                                      22
    Non-Static                                      22 (100.00%)
    Static                                           0 (0.00%)

Structure
  Namespaces                                         2
  Interfaces                                         0
  Traits                                             0
  Classes                                            3
    Abstract Classes                                 0 (0.00%)
    Concrete Classes                                 3 (100.00%)
  Methods                                           11
    Scope
      Non-Static Methods                            11 (100.00%)
      Static Methods                                 0 (0.00%)
    Visibility
      Public Methods                                10 (90.91%)
      Non-Public Methods                             1 (9.09%)
  Functions                                          0
    Named Functions                                  0 (0.00%)
    Anonymous Functions                              0 (0.00%)
  Constants                                          1
    Global Constants                                 0 (0.00%)
    Class Constants                                  1 (100.00%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some more sources / links about the [metrics](https://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/index.html) , [results](https://pdepend.org/documentation/handbook/reports/overview-pyramid.html) and [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937676/phploc-output-explanation) in an old but similar question. If you want more info about mistakes and code smells I would recommand you look intro: [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and [PHP_Depend](https://pdepend.org/documentation/getting-started.html)